# Entity Framework - Custom query to multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I want to fetch database and get list of string arrays. I do..

```
List<string[]> results = new List<string[]>();
results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string[]>("select one, two from myTable").ToList();
```

I have an exception

```
"The result type 'System.String[]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor."
```

But I don't want to create new abstract type. It's just a simple map. Two columns.

What's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

A class that is going to be used in place of TElement should have a default constructor so that the `SQLQuery` method will be able to initialize it before adding it to your `List`.

Therefore if you had a class named `Person` the `SQLQuery` method would do a

```
Person p = new Person();
```

internally and then it would fill its properties

```
Person.One = .... ;
Person.Two = .... ;
```

Instead of a class like above you want to use an array of type string. The problem is that this class has not a default constructor. We can create a new array as

```
string[] someStrings = new string[10];
```

but we cannot create an array of strings as follows

```
string[] someStrings = new string[];
```

because we need to specify how big this array is going to be.

I am afraid you will not be able to achieve what you are trying to do, you will need to use a class with a default constructor in place of `string[]`.

Comment: if myTable maps to an already defined Entity ("MyEntity"), he could return an array via:
           results = dbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Select(e => new string[] { e.one, e.two}).ToArray();